# Is there a way to return current viewed page in QPrintPreviewDialog?

Tags: qt, qt5

I know it is possible with `QPrintPreviewWidget` via `currentPage()` function, but is there a way to return current page in `QPrintPreviewDialog`? Since I like the default `QPrintPreviewDialog`'s interface, and I don't feel confident enough to rebuild it myself, I would like to use `QPrintPreviewDialog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QPrintPreviewDialog is a QDialog that has a QPrintPreviewWidget as internal elements, so using findChild you can obtain that object.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>

#include <QPrintPreviewDialog>
#include <QPrintPreviewWidget>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTimer>

#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextDocument>

#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPrintPreviewDialog previewDialog;

    QObject::connect(&previewDialog, &QPrintPreviewDialog::paintRequested, &previewDialog, [&previewDialog](QPrinter *printer){
        QTextDocument document;
        QTextCursor cursor(&document);
        QTextBlockFormat blockFormat;
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
            cursor.insertBlock(blockFormat);
            cursor.insertHtml(QString("<h1>This is the %1 page</h1>").arg(i+1));
            blockFormat.setPageBreakPolicy(QTextFormat::PageBreak_AlwaysBefore);
        }
        document.print(printer);
        if(QPrintPreviewWidget *previewWidget = previewDialog.findChild<QPrintPreviewWidget *>()){
            qDebug() << previewWidget->currentPage();
            // change page
            QTimer::singleShot(100, previewWidget, [previewWidget](){
                previewWidget->setCurrentPage(2);
            });
        }
    });

    previewDialog.exec();
}
```